# timedelta to integers while ignoring NaT values in a python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, integer, timedelta

I created a timedelta column and got a couple of NaT values, they are actually important for me to conserve. Now I want to transform my timedelta which is now like this: 234 days and NaT values. I want to get integers. These is the code so far:

```
reports['delinquency_free_time'] = reports['delinquency_free_time'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Please note that the days instead of total_seconds also didn't work

Comment: If you really have to use `int` dtype, you could still do so but you'll need to *define* a "not-a-number" identifier, i.e. a value of which you know it won't be valid in your condext, e.g. `-9999` or something similar. Just add a `fillna` before `astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I understood something: I might not convert to int but I can convert to float.

Comment: See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Integer_NaN